# Spring Boot /actuator returns 404 not found

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I am using spring boot `2.1.4.RELEASE` and currently trying to access http://localhost:8080/actuator but i am getting 404 not found. I am not sure what am i doing wrong here. Below is my pom dependencies-

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.dir</groupId>
    <artifactId>api</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Search</name>
    <description>Search</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>Releases</id>
            <name>repo1.releases</name>
            <url>http://www.something.com</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>Snapshots</id>
            <name>repo1.com</name>
            <url>http://repo1.com/artifactory/Snapshots</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>


    <properties>
        <!--These two should be in all ParentPOMs -->
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <!-- Keep this version in sync with the pom's version ignoring "-SNAPSHOT" -->
        <applicationVersion>1.0.0</applicationVersion>
        <elasticsearch.version>5.2.0</elasticsearch.version>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.7</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>x-pack-transport</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>apache-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring boot actuator to expose metrics endpoint -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Micormeter core dependecy  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Micrometer Prometheus registry  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
        </dependency>




    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <environmentVariables>
                        <version>9.9.9</version>
                        <basePath>http://sample-basepath.com</basePath>

                    </environmentVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>

    </build>


</project>
```

properties file config

```
management.endpoint.metrics.enabled=true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoint.prometheus.enabled=true
management.metrics.export.prometheus.enabled=true
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
management.endpoint.beans.enabled=true
```

when i run the application i do see this in console

```
2019-04-27 00:04:25.406  INFO 32522 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 16 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2019-04-27 00:04:25.534  INFO 32522 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path '/myendpoint'
```

Comment: Have you tried `http://localhost:8080/myendpoint/actuator`?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Please check if you have configured **server.servlet.contextPath=/myendpoint**

If you have done like this please try localhost:8080/{server.servlet.contextPath}/actuator

Comment: yes i have configured server.servlet.context-path=/myendpoint but when i tried accessing - localhost:8080/myendpoint/actuator via browser or postman i am getting 401 unauthorized istead of 404 not found.

Comment: My app uses application.yml instead of application.properties and I found the context path setting as

server:
  context-path:
     /some/path

Answer (score 12):

Certain actuator endpoints are disabled, and have to be enabled before you can use them. I was trying to access `/actuator/beans`, which turns out to be just such an endpoint. According to [the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.11.RELEASE/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#production-ready-endpoints-exposing-endpoints), all you need is to enable them in your `application.properties` file:

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health,info,beans
```

Comment: he already has that line in his properties: management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*

Comment: although this wasn't an answer for OP's Question specifically (as jodoro correctly pointed out), this can help other similar scenarios where this property is not yet in place.  (and `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*` enables _all_ Actuator endpoints)

Answer (score 10):

Spring boot Actuator URL changing through SpringBoot Releases,
Initially we can Access Actuator URL with https://localhost:8080/actuator

in early milestone versions of springboot 2.0.0 the URL is https://localhost:8080/application

Now current springboot version it can be access through https://localhost:8080/actuator

Comment: i tried to access https://localhost:8080/actuator instead of http://localhost:8080/actuator and now i am seeing java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name. HTTP method names must be tokens. I believe this is occuring since my client endpoint is not https configured.

Comment: Dear @JonAbraham You have mentioned both as localhost:8080/actuator what is the difference?

Answer (score 8):

I'm using a spring boot.
I got this simple message from spring boot.

```
Spring Boot /actuator returns 404 not found
```

here is my application.yml file.

```
server:
  port: 6150
  servlet:
    context-path: /


management:
  server:
    port: 6150
  endpoints:
    web:
      base-path: /actuator
      exposure:
        include: "*"
```

and then:

```
http://localhost:6150/actuator
```

I know this question is quit old and some situation(condition) is different.
I hopefully someone save their time.

Answer (score 7):

As per above answers Try

```
 http://localhost:8080/<server.servlet.context-path>/actuator/
```

but if it show error so there would be these possible reason is that you not include dependency in you pom.xml

> ```
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
> </dependency>
> ```

Answer (score 6):

I had the same 404 error, even after exactly following Spring documentation. What finally worked for me was deleting actuator dependency and the jar, and adding it again, with a mvn clean install. It worked :)

Answer (score 4):

This was the first result when I googled a similar issue I was having. Unfortunately none of the solutions above worked for me but another source mentioned that I needed to set the management port:

```
management.server.port=8080
```

Which allows me to hit

```
 http://localhost:8080/actuator/
```

Comment: Also consider `management.endpoints.web.base-path=/manage`

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem, but my issue was that the following application property was set in my project:

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      base-path: /
```

Which meant that the actual endpoint for something like:
http://localhost:8080/actuator/beans

was in fact:
http://localhost:8080/beans

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a context path **/myendpoint** in your application.

Please try with this endpoint 
http://localhost:8080/myendpoint/actuator

Comment: I tried this and now i am getting 401 unauthorized.

Comment: can you share full pem.xml file@JonAbraham

Comment: @RAJKUMAR i have posted full POM.xml file for your review

Comment: I see where the problem is in the console after i added actuator dependency i don't see these type of logs -s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/auditevents],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object

Comment: Just an update i was able to see response at - http://localhost:8080/actuator. I simply deleted the actuator jar and did maven clean install. After that i was able to see response

Answer (score 2):

I solved for spring 2.6.x with a bean

```
    @Bean
    public HttpTraceRepository httpTraceRepository() {
        return new InMemoryHttpTraceRepository();
    }
```

as aware for the project instructions on the link: [Spring-Boot-2.2.0-M3-Release-Notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.2.0-M3-Release-Notes#actuator-http-trace-and-auditing-are-disabled-by-default)

Answer (score 1):

It was a version conflict for me which was why the actuator endpoints were not exposed. I removed the version from the pom file for spring-boot-starter-actuator to make it work

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    <!--<version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>-->
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you misunderstand.

Exposed endpoints are in two ways, please read carefully in the docs. One is exposed to JMX, while the other is exposed to WEB.

[image]

Obviously, if you enable the beans endpoint, it only expose to JMX.

Answer (score 0):

For my project, the problem could be resolved by adding the maven-clean-plugin. In the project, I am using the spring-boot-maven-plugin like this:

```
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
  <outputDirectory>./out</outputDirectory>
</configuration>
```

I was not able to view any indicator until using the maven-clean-plugin:

```
<artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
  <filesets>
    <fileset>
      <directory>./out</directory>
    </fileset>
  </filesets>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your log which genereted by ide, you sholud not get something like that in you init log.
**Exposing 13 endpoint(s) beneath base path '**'(if you are getting the same please addd this like to you application.properties **management.endpoints.web.base-path=/actuator**
)
I am talking about log console where you can check as this

[image]

basically, add this line **management.endpoints.web.base-path=/actuator** in your application application.prperties and try.

Answer (score -1):

If you are getting 401 unauthorised then you should add roll "ACTUATOR" in your token, then only you will be able to hit /actuator endpoints of your application.