# 404 when accessing Actuator endpoint

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I added the `compileOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'` to my `build.gradle`, in the Gradle tools window I then right clicked the project and selected `Refresh Gradle Dependencies`. I then added `endpoints.health.enabled=true` to my `application.properties`.

When I start my application and do a GET on URL `http://localhost:9000/application/health` I get the following:

```json
{
    "timestamp": "2021-11-05T11:40:13.663+00:00",
    "path": "/application/",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": null,
    "requestId": "c8352103-2"
}
```

Have I missed something when enabling Actuators?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55877188/spring-boot-actuator-returns-404-not-found this link could help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using Spring Boot 2.x, by default, all Actuator endpoints are placed under the /actuator path, so please try `http://localhost:9000/actuator/health` instead. If `application` is indeed part of your context path, then try `http://localhost:9000/application/actuator/health`.

Also, `compileOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'` should be `implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'`.

Comment: Also note, that you need to set the security rules for actuator in Spring security in a correct way https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-actuators#2-important-changes