# Kubernetes pod with spring application is failing to start (all endpoints with 404)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, kubernetes

My team has a deployment process that involves using Spring's `bootBuildImage` to create the application image, then we deploy it to our Kubernetes cluster. Last week the deployment was working correctly but it suddenly stopped working.

When we try to deploy a new version, the image is created correctly but the pod doesn't get `Ready` because the actuator endpoints return a 404 error.

```bash
curl localhost:8080/actuator/health/liveness
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>HTTP Status 404 – Not Found</title>
        <style type="text/css">body {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;} h1, h2, h3, b {color:white;background-color:#525D76;} h1 {font-size:22px;} h2 {font-size:16px;} h3 {font-size:14px;} p {font-size:12px;} a {color:black;} .line {height:1px;background-color:#525D76;border:none;}</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>HTTP Status 404 – Not Found</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

I already added the health properties (even though we hadn't needed them before)

```
management.endpoint.health.probes.enabled=true
management.health.livenessState.enabled=true
management.health.readinessState.enabled=true
```

This is what Kubernetes says

```
Port:           8080/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Tue, 07 Feb 2023 01:23:27 -0600
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Liveness:       http-get http://:8080/actuator/health/liveness delay=60s timeout=1s period=30s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:      http-get http://:8080/actuator/health/readiness delay=60s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
...
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                From               Message
  ----     ------     ----               ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  2m30s              default-scheduler  Successfully assigned podname to ip-10-8-x-x.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal
  Normal   Pulled     2m29s              kubelet            Container image "registry.gitlab.com/integration-image" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    2m29s              kubelet            Created container ui-backend
  Normal   Started    2m29s              kubelet            Started container ui-backend
  Warning  Unhealthy  30s (x2 over 60s)  kubelet            Liveness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 404
  Warning  Unhealthy  10s (x8 over 80s)  kubelet            Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 404
```

I've also tried:

- extending the checks time
- changing the port of the actuator
- disabling spring tasks

In all of these cases spring starts but gets restarted by kubernetes after failing the readiness checks

```
Setting Active Processor Count to 2
Adding $JAVA_OPTS to $JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS
Calculating JVM memory based on 5201M available memory
For more information on this calculation, see https://paketo.io/docs/reference/java-reference/#memory-calculator
Calculated JVM Memory Configuration: -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=10M -Xmx4528339K -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=285484K -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240M -Xss1M (Total Memory: 5201M, Thread Count: 250, Loaded Class Count: 47989, Headroom: 0%)
Enabling Java Native Memory Tracking
Adding 124 container CA certificates to JVM truststore
NOTE: Picked up JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS:  --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Djava.security.properties=/layers/paketo-buildpacks_bellsoft-liberica/java-security-properties/java-security.properties -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:ActiveProcessorCount=2 -Dspring.profiles.active=dev -Dspring.config.additional-location=optional:file:/config/,optional:file:/secret/ -Dsentry.environment=dev -Dhoneycomb.config.file=/secret/application.properties -javaagent:/workspace/WEB-INF/lib/honeycomb-opentelemetry-javaagent-1.0.0.jar -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=10M -Xmx4528339K -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=285484K -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240M -Xss1M -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:NativeMemoryTracking=summary -XX:+PrintNMTStatistics
[otel.javaagent 2023-02-02 03:27:59:129 +0000] [main] INFO io.opentelemetry.javaagent.tooling.VersionLogger - opentelemetry-javaagent - version: honeycomb-1.0.0-otel-1.12.0
[CONTAINER] org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol         INFO    Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
[CONTAINER] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina               INFO    Server initialization in [968] milliseconds
[CONTAINER] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService           INFO    Starting service [Catalina]
[CONTAINER] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine            INFO    Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.71]
[CONTAINER] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig             INFO    Deploying web application directory [/layers/paketo-buildpacks_apache-tomcat/catalina-base/webapps/ROOT]
[CONTAINER] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner               INFO    At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
[CONTAINER] lina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/] INFO    2 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
{"timestamp":"2023-02-02T03:28:15.334Z","level":"INFO","thread":"main","logger":"app","message":"Starting UiApplication using Java 11.0.18 on ui-backend-7b6ddf8f58-m8vtq with PID 1 (/workspace/WEB-INF/classes started by cnb in /workspace)","context":"default","nanotime":27377774090677176}
{"timestamp":"2023-02-02T03:28:15.388Z","level":"DEBUG","thread":"main","logger":"app","message":"Running with Spring Boot v2.5.8, Spring v5.3.14","context":"default","nanotime":27377774144285955}
{"timestamp":"2023-02-02T03:28:15.388Z","level":"INFO","thread":"main","logger":"app","message":"The following profiles are active: dev","context":"default","nanotime":27377774145291720}
[CONTAINER] lina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/] INFO    Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
{"timestamp":"2023-02-02T03:28:22.755Z","level":"WARN","thread":"main","logger":"org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration","message":"spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning","context":"default","nanotime":27377781511405545}
{"timestamp":"2023-02-02T03:28:38.660Z","level":"INFO","thread":"main","logger":"app.route.ui.report.ReportTemplateRegistry","message":"report template registry -> templates -> {receipt_ja=app.route.ui.report.ReceiptReportTemplate@6dc0e992, invoice_ja=app.route.ui.report.InvoiceReportTemplate@6e221246}","context":"default","nanotime":27377797416315839}
{"timestamp":"2023-02-02T03:28:38.675Z","level":"DEBUG","thread":"main","logger":"app.route.ui.service.ReportService","message":"report service -> initialize -> start","context":"default","nanotime":27377797431868400}
{"timestamp":"2023-02-02T03:28:38.721Z","level":"INFO","thread":"main","logger":"app.route.ui.service.ReportService","message":"report service -> initialize -> cache created succefully","context":"default","nanotime":27377797477131943}
{"timestamp":"2023-02-02T03:28:38.721Z","level":"DEBUG","thread":"main","logger":"app.route.ui.service.ReportService","message":"report service -> initialize -> end","context":"default","nanotime":27377797481925043}
[CONTAINER] freemarker.configuration                           SEVERE  DefaultObjectWrapper.incompatibleImprovements was set to the object returned by Configuration.getVersion(). That defeats the purpose of incompatibleImprovements, and makes upgrading FreeMarker a potentially breaking change. Also, this probably won't be allowed starting from 2.4.0. Instead, set incompatibleImprovements to the highest concrete version that's known to be compatible with your application.
{"timestamp":"2023-02-02T03:28:40.289Z","level":"INFO","thread":"main","logger":"app.route.ui.entity.storage.EntityStorageRegistry","message":"entity storage registry -> interceptors -> [app.route.ui.entity.interceptor.UserInterceptor@3a94d628]","context":"default","nanotime":27377799045261311}
{"timestamp":"2023-02-02T03:28:41.091Z","level":"INFO","thread":"main","logger":"org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain","message":"Will secure Ant [pattern='/actuator/health/**'] with []","context":"default","nanotime":27377799847478125}
{"timestamp":"2023-02-02T03:28:41.092Z","level":"INFO","thread":"main","logger":"org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain","message":"Will secure Ant [pattern='/h2-console/**'] with []","context":"default","nanotime":27377799848958832}
{"timestamp":"2023-02-02T03:28:41.182Z","level":"INFO","thread":"main","logger":"org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain","message":"Will secure Or [Ant [pattern='/admin/user/webhook'], Ant [pattern='/v1/backups/webhoook/**']] with [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@7843b634, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@2f514909, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@22c59a39, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@395a9cdb, app.route.ui.security.internal.ApiKeyAuthFilter@3d042a50, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@1404f97, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@50d8cc71, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@63b040d5, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@75c3b5ab, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@763630ac, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@7753b2e8]","context":"default","nanotime":27377799938730993}
{"timestamp":"2023-02-02T03:28:41.194Z","level":"INFO","thread":"main","logger":"org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain","message":"Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@1c2cee82, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@3c3e87b8, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@58e130bc, org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter@7c067793, org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter@43c49d4c, org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter@233b20ed, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@4eb259f, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@465b750a, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@176ed9ad, org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakSecurityContextRequestFilter@1de33861, org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilter@41dfea3, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@25cb293e, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@76a5b602, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@160d925f, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@3a5e6480]","context":"default","nanotime":27377799956811708}
{"timestamp":"2023-02-02T03:28:42.964Z","level":"INFO","thread":"main","logger":"app","message":"Started UiApplication in 29.288 seconds (JVM running for 44.237)","context":"default","nanotime":27377801720328782}
{"timestamp":"2023-02-02T03:28:43.156Z","level":"DEBUG","thread":"main","logger":"app.route.ui.interceptor.RequestLogFilter","message":"Filter 'requestLogFilter' configured for use","context":"default","nanotime":27377801912945502}
{"timestamp":"2023-02-02T03:28:43.160Z","level":"DEBUG","thread":"main","logger":"app.route.ui.security.UiAuthenticationFilter","message":"Filter 'uiAuthenticationFilter' configured for use","context":"default","nanotime":27377801916847463}
[CONTAINER] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig             INFO    Deployment of web application directory [/layers/paketo-buildpacks_apache-tomcat/catalina-base/webapps/ROOT] has finished in [38,936] ms
[CONTAINER] org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol         INFO    Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
[CONTAINER] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina               INFO    Server startup in [39138] milliseconds
[CONTAINER] org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol         INFO    Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
[CONTAINER] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService           INFO    Stopping service [Catalina]
[CONTAINER] lina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/] INFO    Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
```

I'm not sure if this is a spring or a Kubernetes problem. Thank you.

Edit:
Other things that I've tried are:

- draining the nodes
- running the images with `kubectl run` which starts spring, and I can reach the actuator endpoints but can't do anything else.

Nodes description.

- Node where at least the previous deployment still works

```
Name:               goodnode.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal
Roles:              <none>
Labels:             beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type=m5.large
                    beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/region=ap-northeast-1
                    failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone=ap-northeast-1a
                    k8s.io/cloud-provider-aws=86af69e954aa5c8fc905ce14364ec305
                    kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    kubernetes.io/hostname=goodnode.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal
                    kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    node.kubernetes.io/instance-type=m5.large
                    topology.kubernetes.io/region=ap-northeast-1
                    topology.kubernetes.io/zone=ap-northeast-1a
Annotations:        node.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl: 0
                    volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach: true
CreationTimestamp:  Tue, 22 Mar 2022 00:32:53 -0600
Taints:             <none>
Unschedulable:      false
Lease:
  HolderIdentity:  goodnode.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal
  AcquireTime:     <unset>
  RenewTime:       Tue, 07 Feb 2023 13:13:59 -0600
Conditions:
  Type             Status  LastHeartbeatTime                 LastTransitionTime                Reason                       Message
  ----             ------  -----------------                 ------------------                ------                       -------
  MemoryPressure   False   Tue, 07 Feb 2023 13:11:07 -0600   Tue, 22 Mar 2022 00:32:51 -0600   KubeletHasSufficientMemory   kubelet has sufficient memory available
  DiskPressure     False   Tue, 07 Feb 2023 13:11:07 -0600   Tue, 22 Mar 2022 00:32:51 -0600   KubeletHasNoDiskPressure     kubelet has no disk pressure
  PIDPressure      False   Tue, 07 Feb 2023 13:11:07 -0600   Tue, 22 Mar 2022 00:32:51 -0600   KubeletHasSufficientPID      kubelet has sufficient PID available
  Ready            True    Tue, 07 Feb 2023 13:11:07 -0600   Tue, 22 Mar 2022 00:33:23 -0600   KubeletReady                 kubelet is posting ready status
Addresses:
  InternalIP:   goodnodeip
  Hostname:     goodnode.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal
  InternalDNS:  goodnode.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal
Capacity:
  attachable-volumes-aws-ebs:  25
  cpu:                         2
  ephemeral-storage:           52416492Ki
  hugepages-1Gi:               0
  hugepages-2Mi:               0
  memory:                      7934440Ki
  pods:                        29
Allocatable:
  attachable-volumes-aws-ebs:  25
  cpu:                         1930m
  ephemeral-storage:           47233297124
  hugepages-1Gi:               0
  hugepages-2Mi:               0
  memory:                      7244264Ki
  pods:                        29
System Info:
  Machine ID:                 ec26c540fc98771f
  System UUID:                ec26c540-fc98-77
  Boot ID:                    034cb48b-8129-40
  Kernel Version:             5.4.181-99.354.amzn2.x86_64
  OS Image:                   Amazon Linux 2
  Operating System:           linux
  Architecture:               amd64
  Container Runtime Version:  docker://20.10.7
  Kubelet Version:            v1.21.5-eks-9017834
  Kube-Proxy Version:         v1.21.5-eks-9017834
ProviderID:                   aws:///ap-northeast-1a/i-01a03da4ffb56c6f0
Non-terminated Pods:          (11 in total)
  Namespace                   Name                                                               CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits  Age
  ---------                   ----                                                               ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------  ---
  amazon-cloudwatch           cloudwatch-agent-b2cxj                                             200m (10%)    200m (10%)  200Mi (2%)       200Mi (2%)     322d
  amazon-cloudwatch           fluent-bit-f825k                                                   500m (25%)    0 (0%)      100Mi (1%)       200Mi (2%)     322d
  webapp                application A                            500m (25%)    1 (51%)     2G (26%)         4G (53%)       12h
  webapp                application B                                  0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         12h
  webapp                APP_WITH_PROBLEMS                                         0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         11h
  kube-system                 alb-ingress-controller-aws-load-balancer-controller-76df65d6qrx    0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         12h
  kube-system                 alb-ingress-controller-aws-load-balancer-controller-76df65kwmss    0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         12h
  kube-system                 aws-node-g7bp7                                                     10m (0%)      0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         322d
  kube-system                 coredns-54bc78bc49-6bdv6                                           100m (5%)     0 (0%)      70Mi (0%)        170Mi (2%)     12h
  kube-system                 coredns-54bc78bc49-vh2rv                                           100m (5%)     0 (0%)      70Mi (0%)        170Mi (2%)     12h
  kube-system                 kube-proxy-lt9bq                                                   100m (5%)     0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         322d
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  Resource                    Requests         Limits
  --------                    --------         ------
  cpu                         1510m (78%)      1200m (62%)
  memory                      2403685Ki (33%)  4664010Ki (64%)
  ephemeral-storage           0 (0%)           0 (0%)
  hugepages-1Gi               0 (0%)           0 (0%)
  hugepages-2Mi               0 (0%)           0 (0%)
  attachable-volumes-aws-ebs  0                0
Events:                       <none>
```

- Node where neither the previous deployment nor the new ones work.

```
Name:               badnode.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal
Roles:              <none>
Labels:             beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type=m5.large
                    beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/region=ap-northeast-1
                    failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone=ap-northeast-1c
                    k8s.io/cloud-provider-aws=86af69e954aa5c8fc905ce14364ec305
                    kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    kubernetes.io/hostname=badnode.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal
                    kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    node.kubernetes.io/instance-type=m5.large
                    topology.kubernetes.io/region=ap-northeast-1
                    topology.kubernetes.io/zone=ap-northeast-1c
Annotations:        node.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl: 0
                    volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach: true
CreationTimestamp:  Tue, 22 Mar 2022 00:25:27 -0600
Taints:             <none>
Unschedulable:      false
Lease:
  HolderIdentity:  badnode.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal
  AcquireTime:     <unset>
  RenewTime:       Tue, 07 Feb 2023 13:14:01 -0600
Conditions:
  Type             Status  LastHeartbeatTime                 LastTransitionTime                Reason                       Message
  ----             ------  -----------------                 ------------------                ------                       -------
  MemoryPressure   False   Tue, 07 Feb 2023 13:12:59 -0600   Tue, 22 Mar 2022 00:25:25 -0600   KubeletHasSufficientMemory   kubelet has sufficient memory available
  DiskPressure     False   Tue, 07 Feb 2023 13:12:59 -0600   Tue, 22 Mar 2022 00:25:25 -0600   KubeletHasNoDiskPressure     kubelet has no disk pressure
  PIDPressure      False   Tue, 07 Feb 2023 13:12:59 -0600   Tue, 22 Mar 2022 00:25:25 -0600   KubeletHasSufficientPID      kubelet has sufficient PID available
  Ready            True    Tue, 07 Feb 2023 13:12:59 -0600   Tue, 22 Mar 2022 00:25:57 -0600   KubeletReady                 kubelet is posting ready status
Addresses:
  InternalIP:   badnodeip
  Hostname:     badnode.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal
  InternalDNS:  badnode.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal
Capacity:
  attachable-volumes-aws-ebs:  25
  cpu:                         2
  ephemeral-storage:           52416492Ki
  hugepages-1Gi:               0
  hugepages-2Mi:               0
  memory:                      7934440Ki
  pods:                        29
Allocatable:
  attachable-volumes-aws-ebs:  25
  cpu:                         1930m
  ephemeral-storage:           47233297124
  hugepages-1Gi:               0
  hugepages-2Mi:               0
  memory:                      7244264Ki
  pods:                        29
System Info:
  Machine ID:                 ec28188afbf50b034
  System UUID:                ec28188a-fbf5-0b0
  Boot ID:                    316e2549-9735-4fe4
  Kernel Version:             5.4.181-99.354.amzn2.x86_64
  OS Image:                   Amazon Linux 2
  Operating System:           linux
  Architecture:               amd64
  Container Runtime Version:  docker://20.10.7
  Kubelet Version:            v1.21.5-eks-9017834
  Kube-Proxy Version:         v1.21.5-eks-9017834
ProviderID:                   aws:///ap-northeast-1c/i-056ee5ae8f99b7076
Non-terminated Pods:          (4 in total)
  Namespace                   Name                      CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits  Age
  ---------                   ----                      ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------  ---
  amazon-cloudwatch           cloudwatch-agent-v7kk2    200m (10%)    200m (10%)  200Mi (2%)       200Mi (2%)     322d
  amazon-cloudwatch           fluent-bit-mfhxk          500m (25%)    0 (0%)      100Mi (1%)       200Mi (2%)     322d
  kube-system                 aws-node-qsgkm            10m (0%)      0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         322d
  kube-system                 kube-proxy-nlgxk          100m (5%)     0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         322d
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  Resource                    Requests    Limits
  --------                    --------    ------
  cpu                         810m (41%)  200m (10%)
  memory                      300Mi (4%)  400Mi (5%)
  ephemeral-storage           0 (0%)      0 (0%)
  hugepages-1Gi               0 (0%)      0 (0%)
  hugepages-2Mi               0 (0%)      0 (0%)
  attachable-volumes-aws-ebs  0           0
Events:                       <none>
```

```json
resource "kubernetes_deployment" "ui_backend" {
  metadata {
    name      = local.name
    namespace = local.namespace
    labels = {
      "app.kubernetes.io/name"       = local.name
      "app.kubernetes.io/managed-by" = local.managed_by
    }
  }

  spec {
    replicas = 1

    selector {
      match_labels = {
        "app.kubernetes.io/name"       = local.name
        "app.kubernetes.io/managed-by" = local.managed_by
      }
    }

    template {
      metadata {
        labels = {
          "app.kubernetes.io/name"       = local.name
          "app.kubernetes.io/managed-by" = local.managed_by
        }
      }

      spec {
        service_account_name = local.name

        image_pull_secrets {
          name = "gitlab-auth"
        }

        container {
          image = var.docker_image
          name  = local.name
          env {
            name  = "JAVA_OPTS"
            value = "-Dspring.profiles.active=${var.environment} "
          }

          port {
            container_port = local.application_port
          }

          liveness_probe {
            http_get {
              path = "/actuator/health/liveness"
              port = local.application_port
            }

            initial_delay_seconds = 60
            period_seconds        = 30
          }

          readiness_probe {
            http_get {
              path = "/actuator/health/readiness"
              port = local.application_port
            }

            initial_delay_seconds = 60
            period_seconds        = 10
          }

        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

logs with `logging.level.root=DEBUG`

```
{"timestamp":"2023-02-08T21:28:40.448Z","level":"DEBUG","thread":"main","logger":"org.springframework.boot.availability.ApplicationAvailabilityBean","message":"Application availability state LivenessState changed to CORRECT","context":"default","nanotime":142674280192537}
{"timestamp":"2023-02-08T21:28:40.451Z","level":"DEBUG","thread":"main","logger":"org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter","message":"Creating new Restarter for thread Thread[main,5,main]","context":"default","nanotime":142674282973006}
{"timestamp":"2023-02-08T21:28:40.454Z","level":"DEBUG","thread":"main","logger":"org.springframework.boot.availability.ApplicationAvailabilityBean","message":"Application availability state ReadinessState changed to ACCEPTING_TRAFFIC","context":"default","nanotime":142674286139388}
{"timestamp":"2023-02-08T21:28:40.496Z","level":"DEBUG","thread":"main","logger":"org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.OrderedRequestContextFilter","message":"Filter 'requestContextFilter' configured for use","context":"default","nanotime":142674328227052}
```

Comment: What are the differences between the versions? You actually left out the intersting bits in your logging (which is the information about the start (or non-start) of the application).

Comment: could you post the full pod config yaml?
is port 8080 exposed in the pod config?

Comment: have you checked the context path: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55877188/spring-boot-actuator-returns-404-not-found

Comment: @M.Deinum I added the description of the nodes, apart from the pods they're not different. I also added the full log

Comment: @SimGel yes, te port 8080 is exposed, added the config yaml.

Comment: The app takes some time to start about 30 seconds, is that a problem? You could enable full on debug logging `logging.level.root=DEBUG` or at least for the web stuff `logging.level.web=DEBUG` that will give some information on what is happening.

Comment: @M.Deinum Using the loggin level you suggested I can see the log from my last edit, so I can now confidently say that spring is reaching the readiness state but Tomcat (?) is not binding the port correctly.

Comment: Did the exposed ports change? Here is nothing that should prevent it, so I suggest you go back and check what has changed between the working version and this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `-javaagent:/workspace/WEB-INF/lib/honeycomb-opentelemetry-javaagent-1.0.0.jar`

edit:
Looks like adding `-Dotel.instrumentation.tomcat.enabled=false` will also fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks to stack overflow I can't comment on the question. But my spring boot app did start to have 404 on both actuator and the web parts after adding  opentelemetry-javaagent

Comment: This is the reason, the pod gets ready with the latest tomcat if I either remove or add the new argument. Thanks!

Comment: Isn't that a bug on opentelemetry-javaagent though? What if we want auto-instrumentation on the tomcat library?

Comment: I agree with @kirit
I'm having the same problem, but removing the agent is not an option.